# SVN doesn't work since IPTABLES changed

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, svn

Since I rebooted my Ubuntu server where my svn is installed, I can't access it from my laptop computer. With svnX, when I try to browse my repertory, I get the error :

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'xxx.xxx': Address already in use
```

When I try to update any working copy, I get a different error :

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'xxx.xxx': Operation timed out
```

The whole history is this :

- when I first found out svn wasn't working, I suspected my iptables boot script was not accepting svn connections... which was true so I've changed my iptables rules so that svn connections ARE accepted
- but it didn't change anything : i get the same errors as before!

Here is my iptables now I've rebooted and added SVN, is there any error in this?

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:svn 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full SVN command used? (You can substitute your IP/domain with "example.com".) Also, just to be sure, can you access your SVN repo when you flush your IP tables and set all policies to "ACCEPT"?

Comment: Afer an "iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT" on my server, svn access works!

Comment: But as soon as I set it back to "iptables -P INPUT DROP", svn access doesn't work. My test is to launch the following command from my laptop's terminal : "svn checkout svn://example.com/repos/" and i get the "svn: Can't connect to host 'example.com': Operation timed out" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've made a stupid mistake.

My problem was I had typed :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eht0 --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
```

instead of

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
```

See that **eht** instead of a **eth** ? :(

Sorry for the inconvenience but if this might help, i was glad to be the fool to make this mistake!