# How can I open port in iptables for SVN?

Tags: centos, apache, iptables

How can I open port in iptables for SVN?
port 447, os: centos. Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 447 -j ACCEPT`

But generally speaking, you shouldn't use ports below 1024 for arbitrary things.
Apache usually runs on HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) and handles SVN with module dav_svn

Comment: I'm not sure if its a CentOS vs Ubuntu thing, but port 3690 worked for me. Have a look at this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342279/svn-doesnt-work-since-iptables-changed